# Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso

I'm trying to set up Double Espresso, but that's probably not relevant here. What I'm trying to do is to set up a project in Android Studio using Gradle.

I'm very new to Gradle and build tools in general, though I've successfully used Maven before. Despite an hour of searching I can't find an answer to a very simple question.

In [Jake Wharton's instructions](https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso) it says

> No more fumbling with local jars or dependency conflicts. Pull it in with one line:
>
> > androidTestCompile 'com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3'

Pull in where? Where do I put/execute that command to import the project? In the command prompt? Do I put it in one of the scripts?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a build.gradle file inside your app folder. In that file you can configure your project, "dependencies" and other options. It's very similar to maven. You have another build.gradle file in your root folder from your project. This conf file is more general and call the other build.gradle file.

e.g I have in one of my projects

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.acostela.example"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
            release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.+"
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    compile 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3'
}
```

Dependencies here are similar to maven and the use in that tool of "/".

Gradle take libs from repositories in the same way of maven. In fact you can use the maven repository. You have a tab with the gradle sentence to download libraries.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.assertj/assertj-android/1.0.0

Comment: You're welcome! Hope you have fun using android studio